# Get records from database using background process in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have total 70,000 records in database.
currently i displays all the records in the data gridview.
but it takes too much time.
now i want to load first 100 records when winform load
and then get records using background process.
and bind it to datagridview.
is it possible?if yes how i achieve this?

Comment: yes it is possible... please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

70000 rows bound to datagrid won't make too much sense to end user. It may result in overall application slowdown and high memory usage. User experience might be very bad even if rows will be populated in background.

I would recommend to use filters to limit # of rows that user can see. Another option is to use [virtual mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx)

Comment: thanks the_joric,i decided to display first 100 records then when user scrolls down at that time i added 100 new records to gridview.is it correct logic or not?thanks again for help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq on a datatable, so you can only get the rows that you want to show (using paging). An example :

```
DS.Tables[0].Select().Skip<DataRow>(pageItems * (PageNumber - 1)).Take<DataRow>(pageItems).CopyToDataTable();
```

pageItems, is 100 in your case, and the PageNumber, is the current page selected. In the example I have a dataset DS and getting a copy of the result in a new datatable.

Comment: thanks for giving solution stephen,but my client don't want to use paging.

Comment: In that case use paging with 100 or 200 rows so that app will be faster and  the client will not notice paging because of larger no of rows. You ca trigger the load data when ever the user reaches the 1st row or the last row in the grid. So that at any time say 100 or 200 rows will be there in the grid.